# How to plot function of 3 variables with Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I am new to Octave (and matlab for that matter). I have a function that looks like this

[image]

I would like to plot g(x,0.5,5) say.

Here it is what I tried in Octave

I defined an anonymous function

```
f=@(n,x,t) 1./n.*log(n.*pi.*t).*sin(n.*pi.*x);
```

then another anonymous function

```
g=@(m,x,t)x.^2+sum(f([1:m],x,t));
```

Finally defined

```
x=-1:0.1:1;
plot(x,g(5,x,0.5))
```

but I get an error. Is this the right way of plotting this function? I must be doing a simple beginner error?

Comment: You're using `f(n,x,t)` with `f(1:5, -1:0.1:1,0.5)` i.e. `n` has 5 elements 
and `x` has 21 elements which cannot be multiplied in any way and hence the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `f(n,x,t)`, you are passing a 1-by-5 vector for `n` and a 1-by-21 vector for `x`. These have different numbers of elements, and therefore can't be multiplied element-by-element. However, you can rewrite `f` to accommodate vectors for each and perform the sum from `g` by using matrix multiplication:

```
f = @(n, x, t) (1./n.*log(n.*pi.*t))*sin(pi.*n(:)*x);
g = @(m, x, t) x.^2 + f(1:m, x, t);
```

And now your plot will work:

```
x = -1:0.1:1;
plot(x, g(5, x, 0.5));
```

[image]